# How can I embed a youtube video in reactjs markdown with react-markdown

Tags: reactjs, react-markdown

I am new with ReactJS. I have some problems with `react-markdown`. I want to embed a video using markdown.

Here is my simple example of my problem.

```
// import react-markdown
import ReactMarkdown from 'react-markdown'

// markdown string
const md = `
   Hello video embeded fro youtube.
   {/* how can I embed a video here */}
`

// use markdown
<ReactMarkdown
 linkTarget="_blank"
> {md} </ReactMarkdown>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this by writing a **iframe** inside the markdown.

For this to work you'll need to install [rehype-raw](https://github.com/rehypejs/rehype-raw) which is a plugin you can use with `ReactMarkdown`.

```bash
yarn add rehype-raw
# or
npm install rehype-raw --save
```

Then you can use it like this

```js
import rehypeRaw from "rehype-raw";

const md = `Hello this video is embeded from Youtube!

<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/JvwW5Tsf97c" />`;

return (
  <ReactMarkdown rehypePlugins={[rehypeRaw]} linkTarget="_blank">
    {md}
  </ReactMarkdown>
);
```

Note that you'll need a **embed** Youtube link and not a **?watch=** link.

Answer (score -1):

```js
    const App = () => {
  const data = `lorem <b onmouseover="alert('mouseover');">ipsum</b>`;

  return (
    <div
      dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: data}}
    />
  );
}

export default App;


const App = () => {
  const data = `lorem ipsum <img src="" onerror="alert('message');" />`;

  return (
    <div
      dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: data}}
    />
  );
}

export default App;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: How does this work with `react-markdown`?